# Using Python to create blank folders in users' directories

Tags: python, directory, creation

I have created a Python script to create new folders in users' directories. It works well however, if the program is run again, then for some reason it will make blank folders in the root directory. As an example

Root
- Dave

- Jim
- Bob

After the program runs once

- Dave

---- Science

---- English

---- Maths

- Jim

---- Science

---- English

---- Maths

- Bob

---- Science

---- English

---- Maths

After the program has run again (just incase a new user gets added) this happens

- Science
- English
- Maths
- Dave

---- Science

---- English

---- Maths

- Jim

---- Science

---- English

---- Maths

- Bob

---- Science

---- English

---- Maths

If the program is run then again, it works.

Any help would be appreciated.

Ta

Code is here:

```
import os

currentPath = os.getcwd()
folders = ["English","Science","Maths"]

directory_list = list()
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(currentPath, topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        directory_list.append(os.path.join(root, name))

        path = currentPath+"\\"+name

        for i in range(len(folders)):

            try:  
                os.makedirs(path+"/"+folders[i])
            except OSError:  
                print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % path)
            else:  
                print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % path)
```

Comment: You have to make sure when you run again, you delete the previous folders. OR you have to check what exists already and whatever is new add only that!!. Right now in your code, when you run again new values like "Science" "Maths" from the 1st run are getting picked and hence the distorted file structure

Comment: You don't need `os.walk` to find the user directories: They're all in the same folder together. Do a straight listing in that and you avoid all problems with descending in existing folders (not just the ones _you_ created earlier.)

Comment: @RahulAgarwal thank you for that, however, I only need the new folders to be added if there is an existing folder there.

Comment: @alexis what do you mean?

Comment: @NeosNokia I have an example of what he means in my Answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first check to see if the directory exists before creating a new on with the same name.

```
import os

currentPath = os.getcwd()
folders = ["English","Science","Maths"]

directory_list = list()
for dir in os.listdir(currentPath):

    temp_path = currentPath+"\\"+dir

    if os.path.isdir(temp_path):
        for folder in folders:
            if not os.path.isdir(temp_path+"\\"+folder):
                new_folder = temp_path+"\\"+folder
                try:
                    os.makedirs(temp_path+"\\"+folder)
                except OSError:  
                    print ("Creation of the directory %s failed" % new_folder)
                else:  
                    print ("Successfully created the directory %s " % new_folder)
```

I had to rewite a bit of the code, but I tested this and it works!

I think writing to the var `path` was giving unintended behavior so I renamed the variable.

Comment: `or else it could delete the old folder and everything in it.` That's not true. You can't create a directory that already exists. `os.makedirs()` will swallow the OS error and continue working.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for your help.

Comment: @NeosNokia if this is the solution you were looking for you can 'Accept' the answer.